# Why did the Nether generate in the Overworld of this map file?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have this world file that somehow generated the Nether inside of the Overworld. Why did this happen? I have tried opening up this world on an older update (where the Nether update didn’t exist) and it just instantly crashed Minecraft whenever I opened it.

The Nether rack looks old because I’m using an old Minecraft themed texture pack, not because I’m playing on the old version, because it simply crashed.

[image: my world with the nether randomly in the Overworld]

Comment: I cleaned up your post to be more direct about what it is you are asking.  I also deleted your answer and moved it into the edit.  You can [edit your own post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/396491/edit) to add information.

Comment: hey could you share the seed?  I want to see if that happens on my computer.

Comment: Where are you seeing that? (Solo or on a server)? Any mods in play?

Comment: Sorry this isn’t a seed and the only mod I am using is this mob animations mod which in it this hasn’t happened before. @Timmy Jim thanks

Comment: @NoobisDude "this isn't a seed" that's impossible. Every world has its seed, even if you didn't set seed. Type `/seed` in in-game chat, and tell us the result.

Comment: For future reference, please don't edit your post to simply add "thank you".  I've reverted this edit.

Comment: The thing is the seed doesn’t work it is the same seed but spawns you thousands of blocks away for some reason then when you get there it isn’t there idk

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft only loaded the spawn point of the nether, to later render in the rest. Minecraft interpreted, as there was originally 1 dimension in earlier versions, that the nether was part of the overworld. it added the nbt (or data) of the nether (Or at least what it loaded) on top of the overworld's nbt. that is why it had the nether in the overworld! Also nice wallpaper. :D

Comment: But this is no earlier version. And why do you think it first only loaded the spawn point, to later fill in the rest?

Comment: Thanks that might be it I think I took the photo on 1.16 as I tried a few different versions. Also thx for saying my wallpaper is nice :)

Comment: @Joachim I think he thinks that because the coordinates weren’t near spawn I’m pretty sure I loaded in at somewhere around 448, 64, 122

Answer (score -1):

You could have merely added a Nether Biome to your World. It could very well be that that was the ONLY biome added.

Comment: Nope you can clearly see dark oak trees in the pic.